# How to insert value (data) to a field reference by ID of the specific row (record) in the delphi clientdataset

Tags: delphi

I am trying to insert a data to a field referenced by specific ID of row (or record) in the clientdataset at runtime.

I am using delphi and here's the structure of my case — mysql database > mysqluniprovider > uniquery > dataset provider > clientdataset > datasource > dbgrid.

The data I am trying to insert is generated during runtime by another code in the same procedure. Hence, dbnavigator will not work for me here. On the otherhand, I prefer to do this at the clientdataset level and do not want to direct to sql.

I was able to find the reference id by using the clientdataset.lookup/locate/findkey. But I could not be able to direct the cursor to the cell of the same row of reference id and specific field to insert the data.

I believed there must be a code component for this type of case just like cds.lookup/locate/findkey to update data in an existing table at runtime.

I will greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using a TDBGrid to display the data is incidental, you change the data in the clientdataset and the TDBGrid will automatically update its  display of the record.  What you neeed to do is to use methods of of the clientdataset to move to the record and update its field data.  You can use the clientdataset's `Locate` method to move to the record you want, as in:

```
ID := 99;  //  the ID of the record to change

if ClientDataSet1.Locate('ID', ID, []) then begin
  ClientDataSet1.Edit;  //  Put the CDS into dsEdit mode so you can change its field data
  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('SomeField').AsString := 'Whatever';
  ClientDataSet1.Post;  // save the change(s) to the record
end;
```

See the online help for `TField` for its various `AsXXX` methods, such as `AsInteger`, `AsFloat`, etc.

Comment: MartynA, it works for me so smooth. Thank you so much.